# Is there a way to force a closest hit shader?

Tags: raytracing, shader, vulkan, optix

I want to add a debug feature to my ray tracer (runs in both Vulkan and OptiX). For that, I'd like to switch *all* objects to use a specific closest hit shader. Can I do this? I have only found the shader offset, but I wouldn't be able to get all objects to use the same shader that way.

The alternative I'm using right now is to rebuild the acceleration structures with the hardcoded shader index, but that seems to be a lot of computation for a conceptually simple problem...